# How to inspect the element in table tag using VBA

Tags: vba, web-scraping

Below is my code, I couldn't enter the values in user name and password field, I don't have an element Id, however I have element name, Could anyone help with what I am doing wrong please. When I run this code I don't get any error messages as well.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer

Sub Login()
    Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
    Dim MyURL As String
    On Error GoTo Err_Clear
    MyURL = "#################"
    Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
    MyBrowser.Silent = True
    MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
    MyBrowser.Visible = True

    Do
    Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
    HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("BrandContext").selectedIndex = 1
    HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("UserId")(0).Value = "Test"
    HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("Password")(0).Value = "Test"
    HTMLDoc.all.Password.Value = "abc+123" 'Enter your password here

    For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName(“input”)
        If MyHTML_Element.Type = “submit” Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
    Next

    Err_Clear:
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is my source code,

```
    <input name="Key" type="hidden" value="u126**80285038-1536**4880">
<select tabindex="1" name="BrandContext">
      
      <option value="**"> **</option>
      
      <option value="**"> **</option>
      
      <option value="**"> ****</option>
      
      <option value="**" selected=""> **</option>
      
      <option value="**"> **</option>
      
      <option value="**"> **</option>
      
   </select>
            <td>
        <input tabindex="1" name="UserId" size="9" maxlength="9" value=""> </td>
```

Comment: It's always useful to mention *what happens when you run your code*.  BTW you're missing the (0) from `HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("BrandContext")`

Comment: Hi Tim,  thanks for the reply, I am not getting any error message. Yes I tried with (0) as well. The way I select username and password is correct, please.

Comment: What if you comment out the error handler?  That's basically the equivalent of `On Error Resume Next`  And put the `(0)` - it should be there like the other lines.

Comment: I tried, Removing codes related to error validation, now when I run the code, it opens URL, I am also getting error message "Automation error The interface is unknown."

Comment: Is the error at some specific place in your code?

Comment: I am getting Error message:Object doesn't support this property or method, at line "HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("BrandContext").selectedIndex = 1"

Comment: Did you add the `(0)` like I suggested?  BTW you have some "smart quotes" in your code - if those are in your original code you need to replace them with regular quotes.

Comment: Yes, I tried with 0, HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("BrandContext")(0).selectedIndex = 2, still not working. Here is the html code, <select tabindex="1" name="BrandContext">

Comment: I can't offer much else without any way to test.

Comment: BrandContext is not in the html you shared in your question. Use [edit] to add it into your question. Also, are there other elements with that name in the html? Particularly that appear higher up the DOM?

Comment: @QHarr - Thanks for the reply, I updated the code, yes it has only one BrandContext

Comment: So with ie.document.querySelector("[name='BrandContext']").SelectedIndex = 1 what is the current error message?